# Redundant physical interfaces for Cisco pseudowire-class

Tags: cisco-ios, l2tp

I have a link which is LT2P from a site router R1 (Cisco 867-VAE, IOS 15.3) which has two external interfaces defined (dialer1 and vlan-1000), but only one plugged in (first is ADSL, second is technician's 4g router)

```
   Exterior view               Tunnel view

   R99                         R99
    |                           |vpp1
   cloud                        |
    ||                          |
  d1||vlan1000                  |vpp1
    R1                          R1
```

All of this works fine with either `ip local interface Dialer1` or `ip local interface vlan1000` in the configuration of the pseudowire-class.

My question is how do I make my virtual-PPP interface work according to whether either interface is plugged in and working **without having to reconfigure `psuedowire-class`?**  It seems I can't add a second `pseudowire` inside `int virtual-ppp1`, nor a second `ip local` inside `pseudowire-class`.  Do I have to have a whole extra `virtual-ppp2` and `pseudowire-class`?

Interface config of R1 has two dynamic-address external interfaces:

```
interface Vlan1000
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
interface Dialer1
 ip address negotiated
 ip nat outside
 ...

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 dhcp
```

This is the tunnelling configuration:

```
pseudowire-class PWCLASS
 encapsulation l2tpv2
 ip local interface Dialer1

interface Virtual-PPP1
 ip address negotiated
 pseudowire R99-exernal-address 1 encapsulation l2tpv2 pw-class PWCLASS
 ...
```

```
System image file is "flash:c860vae-advsecurityk9_npe-mz.153-3.M.bin"
```

Comment: Have you tried creating an additional Virtual PPP interface and then add another pseudowire-class as you describe yourself?